# JWT library for Grails 2.2.x?

Tags: grails, jwt

I'm having surprising difficulty getting hold of a JWT library which works with Grails 2.2.x, and I'm hoping someone can point me in the right direction. Stormpath's JJWT looks promising (https://github.com/jwtk/jjwt), but I am running into all kinds of dependency issues which I can't resolve. There seems to be a plugin which latches on to Spring Security (http://plugins.grails.org/plugin/grails/spring-security-rest) but I'm not actually using Spring Security - not sure if I have to. Any useful pointers would be welcome!

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. Nimbus JOSE + JWT (https://connect2id.com/products/nimbus-jose-jwt) works fine. I downloaded the 2 necessary jar files, nimbus-jose-jwt-4.34.2.jar and a dependency, json-smart-2.2.1.jar, from the Maven repo.